# Angular ngRoute: Why is $resolve not available on scope in directive link function?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, resolve

In my Angular v1.4.8 app using [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute), I have a route with a resolve that I want to access in the link function of a custom directive.

According to the docs:

> For easier access to the resolved dependencies from the template, the
>   resolve map will be available on the `scope` of the route, under
>   `$resolve` (by default) or a custom name specified by the `resolveAs`
>   property.

...yet `$resolve` is undefined on the `scope` property in my custom directive's link function -- even when I watch it for changes.

Why is `$resolve` not available on `scope`?

**Code:** ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gL2d8mus/1/))

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(routeConfig)
  .directive('myDirective', myDirective)
;

function routeConfig($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      resolve: {
        data: function($q) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          deferred.resolve('foo');
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      },
      template: '<my-directive></my-directive>'
    })
    .otherwise('/')
  ;
}

function myDirective($route) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      console.log($route.current.locals); // contains data
      console.log(scope.$resolve); // undefined
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return scope.$resolve;
      }, function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue); // undefined, never changes
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This paragraph is in the documentation for the 1.5 version, but not in the documentation of the 1.4.x version, that you're using. So it's something new in 1.5.

Comment: Relevant pull request (tagged for 1.5.0-rc.0): https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/13400

Comment: I guess it helps to read the correct version of the manual. Thank you!